# Linear algebra: Matrix multiplication problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I need to prove something in my homework I just don't know how to approach it and need some guidance.

"Show that for a matrix $A$ ($n \times m$) and a vector $\vec{x}$ ($m \times 1$) it applies that:

$A\vec{x} = \sum_{j=1}^{j=m} x_jA_j$

s.t the multiplication of $x_jA_j$ is a multiply of vector $A_j$
and the scalar $x_j$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just write that stuff down explicitly. If $\;A=(a_{ij})\;$ , then

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1m}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2m}\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nm}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\ldots\\x_m\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{k=1}^ma_{1k}x_k\\\ldots\\\sum_{k=1}^ma_{nk}x_k\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^mx_k\begin{pmatrix}a_{1k}\\a_{2k}\\\ldots\\a_{nk}\end{pmatrix}$$